# Prove $p(x)=\frac{6}{(\pi x)^2}$ for $x=1,2,...$where $p$ is a probability function. and $E[X]$ doesn't exist.

Tags: probability

Prove $p(x)=\frac{6}{(\pi x)^2}$ for $x=1,2,...$where $p$ is a probability function.  and $E[X]$ doesn't exists.

**My work**

I know $\sum _{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Moreover,

$p(1)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$
$p(2)=\frac{6}{\pi^24}$
$p(3)=\frac{6}{\pi^29}$
$p(4)=\frac{6}{\pi^216}$
.
.
.

Then, for prove $p$ is a probability function then i need prove

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{6}{(\pi x)^2}=1
$

Then, 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{6}{(\pi x)^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{6}{\pi^2 x^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\times\frac{\pi^2}{6}=1$

In consequence,
$p$ is a probability function.

> Moreover, i need prove $E[X]$ doesn't exist.

Here i'm a little stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: First problem: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=0$

Comment: I'm using $\sum _{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ @vadim123

Comment: limit is not the same thing as sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{E[x]} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x\frac{6}{\pi^2 x^2} = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x} $  which is the harmonic series and is divergent, thus  the random variable X with probability function as described above doesn't have a finite Expected value

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: What can you say about $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot \dfrac 6{(\pi n)^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

To have a probability mass function of a discrete RV what you need is not $\lim_{x\to \infty}p(x)=1$ but rather $\sum_{x\in\Bbb R}p(x)=1$, where the sum over real numbers is well defined because $p(x)$ is non-zero only countably many times.

Then for the expectation use a comparison with the harmonic series.